# Can't call functions from a JS file in HTML in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

**Quick summary:** I have a function in a .js file that's loaded thanks to wp_enqueue_scripts. Now when I try to call that function from the HTML in one of my template files, it doesn't seem to work...

I've researched this and I think I'm doing it all right, but obviously I must have missed something and can't quite put my finger on what it is.

---

.

So, in ***functions.php***, I have the following code:

```
function script_assets() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'js-code', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/js-code.js' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'script_assets' );
```

This works as intended, and results in this being added to the head:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://.../js/js-code.js?ver=4.1.1'></script>
```

.

*Then,* in ***header.php***, after `wp_head();` I have the following bit of code:

```
<?php if ( !is_front_page() ) : ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    /* <![CDATA[ */
        setTimeout(function(){ deploy($("#rightsec .deployer")); }, 200);
        setTimeout(function(){ switchMobile($("#switcher")); }, 200);
    /* ]]> */
    </script>
    
<?php endif; ?>
```

The PHP bit works correctly, the script tags and everything in between go into the HTML whenever I'm not on the front page as intended. It goes after ***js-code.js*** is loaded via the line I pasted above. Both `deploy()` and `switchMobile()` are functions in ***js-code.js*** and I know they work, as I use them with no issue in a different context.

However Chrome throws

> Uncaught ReferenceError: deploy is not defined
>
> Uncaught ReferenceError: switchMobile is not defined

and the functions are not executed...

I know the question of 'how to call JS functions from HTML' has been asked countless times, but like I said I've been reading many pages and they all seem to say the same thing, which I've followed to the letter, and it still doesn't work...

Any ideas? Thanks.

---

**New developments:**

So, it turns out that, for some weird reason, if I only call the functions without using `setTimeout()`, the second one* — `switchMobile()` — works properly... but not the first one. If I reverse them so that `deploy()` is after `switchMobile()`, then this time `deploy()` works. I am utterly confused :s

*for the sake of clarity my initial example only had one function, when in practice I am calling two. I've edited the question to reflect that.

---

**UPDATE**

Tried enclosing the function calls in `$(document).ready(function(){ .. });`, tried using `switchMobile(jQuery('#switcher'));`, tried not using JQuery at all (with `document.getElementById("switcher")`)... Nothing works. Adding an `alert()` right next to the function calls works as intended...

Comment: Is `switchMobile` called before the file has been initialised?

Comment: No, it's called after it. However I tried loading the file in the footer and it doesn't solve anything.

Comment: Is the function.php file you are calling wp_enqueue_script from a child them or the main theme?

Comment: it's in my child theme, the one I'm using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it was a scope issue and I had to enclose the function call like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    deploy($('#rightsec .deployer'));
});
```

There might be other ways to do it but it works like that so I'm not changing it.